# Aspx page does not display iso-8859-1 character

Tags: asp.net, doctype, iso, iso-8859-1

On my site: http://tangobue.simpletick.com/

I see the text:

```
<p>Todos los shows de tango en un s�lo lugar.</p>
```

However in my aspx code I have:

```
<p>Todos los shows de tango en un sólo lugar.</p>
```

What should I change so the accent appears correctly?

I have this on the top of my master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: Are you sure the `aspx` file is encoded in `iso-8859-1` and not `UTF-8`?

Comment: Do I check the web.config for that?

Comment: No, you check the file itself - open it in notepad++ and check the encoding. BTW - the server side header for the page you linked is `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: What do I want? utf-8 or iso-8859-1 ?

Comment: I don't know - which one do you want? Which one _are_ you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Oded!

Based on your suggestion I found this solution:

I updated the web config and changed UTF-8 to: "iso-8859-1"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization 
         requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```